# How can I find a method caller when stepping through C# in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

If I set a breakpoint on a method, how can I see what called the method, when the breakpoint is hit in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Right click and "Go to definition"?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ahhh my newb days.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Check the Call Stack window (from the menu: Debug > Windows > Call Stack). Double clicking each entry there will take you to the calling statement. You can also right click on it to enable/disable showing external code items and calls from other threads.

Comment: This is the general way to do it. Unless the method is inlined (which is weird if it's a debug build), there should be something problematic in your specific case.

Comment: Inlining is an optimization in which a method call is replaced by the body of the method called.

Comment: I'm not sure if inlinig is used in .NET.

Comment: JIT optimizer does inlining in .NET. It doesn't do that for debug builds or when you are running from a debugger (it does if you attach the debugger after launching a release build with optimizations on.)

Comment: It just started working. I don't think I changed anything. I now have 3 more things in my call stack window that shows the path of execution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When the breakpoint is hit, you can view the entire call stack. You can bring that window up by going through the Debug menu->Windows->Call Stack.

You can also bring it up by the shortcut Alt+Ctrl+C

EDIT:
You can also right-click on a function name, and view the "Callers Graph", which will show you all the callers for your method. Alternatively, you can bring the Call Browser (by going to View->Other windows->Call Browser ) and search for your method's name.

Comment: + for the shortuct ctrl + alt + C and callers graph.

Comment: nice idea to trace all flow of calling method

Answer (score 4):

If you can't see anything in the call stack *at a user-set breakpoint*, it generally means it was called from native code.

Another case where it can't get a stack: You hit Debug>Break All and the main thread is in a wait/sleep state, the debugger can have problems building the call stack. I believe the debugger uses the main thread for its implicit function evaluation.

Try attaching (or launching) the mixed-mode (native & managed) code debugger and see if that straightens it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see anything in the Call Stack window, then there's definitely something wrong. I would suggest the famous sequence of R-actions:

- Retry
- Recompile
- Restart
- Reinstall :)

Answer (score 1):

If the break point is in a function that is raised by an event, you might not have a direct call stack back to the caller, and will need to enable viewing all code, and not just "just my code".

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2019 Open **View** menu and select **Call Hierarchy**,
or simply press **CTRL+ALT+K**